# setseed() and random() behaviour

Tags: postgresql

Why this returns different random numbers in every column? I thought that I will get always the same random numbers if I use `setseed()`. But it looks like there is new constant vector of random numbers for every invocation of `random()`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/995)

```
select setseed(0.5);
select 
   random(), 
   random(),
   random()
from 
   generate_series(1,20);
```

Returns every time:

```
0.798512778244913;0.518533017486334;0.0734698106534779
0.563445927575231;0.00328421639278531;0.859378454275429
0.537976825609803;0.567121817730367;0.311047440394759
0.420166166499257;0.203177386429161;0.125661129131913
0.754696044139564;0.424046442843974;0.202209176961333
...
```

Now I see (thanks to Ed Heal) that random numbers are generated by rows. To prove this:

```
select setseed(0.5);
select random(), random(), random();

select setseed(0.5);
select random()
union all
select random()
union all
select random();
```

Is this not a little bit strange? I mean, why it does not work column-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this part of the query

```
select 
   random(), 
   random(),
   random()
```

Is generating three random numbers for a row!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the same value in all columns:

```
select r, r, r
from
    (
        select random() r
        from generate_series(1,3)
    ) s
;
         r         |         r         |         r         
-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 0.607540448661894 | 0.607540448661894 | 0.607540448661894
 0.973879527300596 | 0.973879527300596 | 0.973879527300596
 0.659207154065371 | 0.659207154065371 | 0.659207154065371
```

Your idea works like this:

```
select setseed(0.5), random(), setseed(0.5), random();
 setseed |      random       | setseed |      random       
---------+-------------------+---------+-------------------
         | 0.798512778244913 |         | 0.798512778244913
```

But I don't know how reliable is that.